# Disable postgres from listening on IPv6

Tags: postgresql, docker

I created a postgres docker image on top of the official image to copy my own `pg_hba.conf` into it, because I need to disable listening on IPv6 :

```
FROM postgres:13
COPY pg_hba.conf /etc/
```

Afterwards I run the container using the following docker-compose.yaml:

```
postgres:
    image: custom-postgres
    command: postgres -c hba_file="/etc/pg_hba.conf"
```

But postgres still tries listening on the none existent IPv6 socket. What am I doing wrong? This is my `pg_hba.conf`:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     trust
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
```

But I get the feeling it is not beeing used as I can see that the default `pg_hba.conf` is still created in `/var/lib/postgresql/data`

Comment: Why not set [listen_addresses](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-connection.html) to `0.0.0.0`?

Comment: Worth a shot, but still, the above approach should be working if I interpret the documentation correctly

Comment: You aren't. `pg_hba.conf` filters the IPs of clients trying to connect. You want Postgres not to listen on the IPv6 interface, for that you need to modify `listen_addresses`.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver That is worth an answer.

Comment: It actually works, thanks! Totally misinterpreted the documentation. If you answer, I can mark it as correct solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to shape what interface(s) the Postgres server listens on you need to use the [listen_addresses](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-connection.html) in `postgresql.conf`. To restrict to IPv4 then set to `0.0.0.0`. See documentation link for more options. `pg_hba.conf` is used to control client access to a server. It does not control what interface the server listens on.